# Fetch different data types values from string and separate them

Tags: iphone, nsstring, qr-code

I am using QR code and after scanning getting username, eventtitle and ticketcode. I need to get these values separately in three different strings, so that i can save them in sqlite. I want to know only how to do this separation, saving is i can do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have a string that contains str={randeepevent151001}, and i want to separate these 3 values accordingly.

Comment: If your string contains some separator then you can use componentsSeparatedByString to get different strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)saveData {
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", @"NameString", @"Address", @"Phone"];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Success");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
}
```

**Note**
If you post what type of string you are getting, i will add how exactly you have to split it.
Below is example how you can split

```
NSArray arrResult = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
```

**Or By Character set**

```
NSString* str = @"A string with newlines in it";

NSArray *arrTemp =  [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Can we split it on the base of space rather than any symbol, because i am fetching plain text.

Comment: Yes we can with space, here is example, 

NSString* str = @"A string with newlines in it";
NSArray *arrTemp =  [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

Answer (score 0):

you can use `componentsSeparatedByString`

```
NSString *str = @"userName:Password:etc";
NSArray* parts1 = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];     
NSLog(@" [[parts1 objectAtIndex:0] integerValue]=%d", [[parts1 objectAtIndex:0] integerValue]);

//the output will be: username for index 0, and so on
```

Comment: Can we split it on the base of space rather than any symbol, because i am fetching plain text.